# My program will not compile through command line even though everything works in Eclipse

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I cant figure out why my program will not compile when using javac in command prompt. however it works in eclipse and no errors show up. How is it possible that this compiles on my laptop without any issues with Java version 1.8.0 and not on my desktop computer which runs 9.0.1

This is what i get when i try and compile it on cmd

```
    test.java:14: error: error while writing Test:
    C:\Users\JohnD\Desktop\Test\Test.class
    public class Test {

    1 error
```

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BookCollection bc = new BookCollection ();
    bc.addNewBook("Big Java", "Horstmann", 2014, 150.0,"Paperback");
    bc.addUsedBook("Java", "Deitel", 1999, 120.0, 90.0);
    bc.addNewBook("JavaScript", "Hoque", 2005, 80.50, "Hardcover");
    bc.addNewBook("C++", "Smith", 2004, 135.0, "Paperback");
    bc.addUsedBook("C", "Jones", 2000, 110.0, 66.0);

    bc.printReport();
    System.out.println("****************************************");
    bc.printAllBooksWithSellingPriceBelow(100.0);
    bc.printAllPaperbackBooks();
 }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////BOOK CLASS

class Book{
private String title;
private String author;
private int year;
private double price;
private String type; 
private double sellingPrice;

Book(String title, String author, int year, double price){}
                     /*****************************************************/

public String toString() {
    return "Title: " + title + "\nAuthor: " + author + "\nYear: " + year + "\nPrice: " + price ;

}
                   /*********************SET METHODS********************************************/   
void setTitle(String t) {
    title = t;
}
void setAuthor(String auth) {
    author = auth;
}
void setYear(int yr) {
    year = yr;
}
void setPrice(double prce) {
    price = prce;
}

void setType(String t) {
    type = t;
}

void setSellingPrice(double sp) {
    sellingPrice = sp;
}
                /***************************GET METHODS*******************************/ 
String getType() {
    return type;
}

double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

double getSellingPrice() {
    return sellingPrice;
} 
}

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////NEW BOOK CLASS

class NewBook extends Book{
private String type;
NewBook(String NEWBOOK_TITLE, String NEWBOOK_AUTHOR, int NEWBOOK_YEAR, double NEWBOOK_PRICE, String NEWBOOK_TYPE){
    super(NEWBOOK_TITLE, NEWBOOK_AUTHOR, NEWBOOK_YEAR, NEWBOOK_PRICE);
        super.setTitle(NEWBOOK_TITLE);
        super.setAuthor(NEWBOOK_AUTHOR);
        super.setYear(NEWBOOK_YEAR);
        super.setPrice(NEWBOOK_PRICE);
        type =NEWBOOK_TYPE;
        super.setType(type);
}

public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + "\nType: " + type + "\n" ;
}
}

   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////USED BOOK CLASS

class UsedBook extends Book{
private double sellingPrice;
UsedBook(String USEDBOOK_TITLE, String USEDBOOK_AUTHOR, int USEDBOOK_YEAR, double USEDBOOK_PRICE, double USEDBOOK_SELLINGPRICE){

    super(USEDBOOK_TITLE, USEDBOOK_AUTHOR, USEDBOOK_YEAR, USEDBOOK_PRICE);
    super.setTitle(USEDBOOK_TITLE);
    super.setAuthor(USEDBOOK_AUTHOR);
    super.setYear(USEDBOOK_YEAR);
    super.setPrice(USEDBOOK_PRICE);
    sellingPrice = USEDBOOK_SELLINGPRICE;
    super.setSellingPrice(sellingPrice);
}

public String toString(){
    return super.toString() + "\nSelling Price: " + sellingPrice + "\n" ;
}

 }
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Book Collection

class BookCollection{
private int MAX_LIMIT=1000;
private int count=0;
private ArrayList<Book> collection = new ArrayList <Book>(count);

void addNewBook(String pTitle, String pAuthor, int pYear, double pPrice, String pType) {
    if (count < MAX_LIMIT) {
        count++;
        NewBook nb = new NewBook(pTitle, pAuthor, pYear, pPrice, pType);
        collection.add(nb);
    }else {
        System.out.println("max volume");
    }   
}
                           /*****************************************************************/  
void addUsedBook(String pTitle, String pAuthor, int pYear, double pPrice, double pSellingPrice) {
    if (count < MAX_LIMIT) {
        count++;
        UsedBook ub = new UsedBook(pTitle, pAuthor, pYear, pPrice, pSellingPrice);
        collection.add(ub);
    }else {
        System.out.println("max volume");
    }
}
                            /*****************************************************************/

void printReport() {
    int bookIndex=0;
    for(int i = 0; i<collection.size(); i++){
        bookIndex++;
        if(collection.get(i).getType() != null) {
            System.out.println("Book " + bookIndex +":" + " New book" +"\n"+ collection.get(i));
        }else 
            System.out.println("Book " + bookIndex +":" +" Used book" +"\n"+ collection.get(i));
    }
}

                            /**********************************************************/    
void printAllBooksWithSellingPriceBelow(double budget) {
        int index=0;
    System.out.println(" \n******* BOOKS BELOW  $" + budget);
    for (int j = 0; j< collection.size(); j++) {
        index++;
        if (collection.get(j).getSellingPrice()!= 0.0){
            System.out.println("Book " + index +":Used Book" +" \n" + collection.get(j));
        }
        if (collection.get(j).getType() != null && collection.get(j).getPrice()<100) {
            System.out.println("Book " + index +":New Book" + " \n" + collection.get(j));
        }
    }
}
                        /*****************************************************************/

void printAllPaperbackBooks() {
    int index = 0; 
    System.out.println("*********" + " ALL PAPERBACK BOOKS");       
    for (int i = 0; i< collection.size();i++) {
        index++;
        String type = collection.get(i).getType();
        if(type != null && type.equals("Paperback")) {
            System.out.println("Book " + index +":NewBook" +"\n" + collection.get(i));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should add your `javac ...` command...

Comment: `test.java:14: error: error while writing Test:` is that the whole error message? Isn't there anything else like `(Permission denied)`?

Comment: @JohnD by `9.0.1` you meant Java 1.9 ?

Comment: @Betlista We stopped using Java 1.x notation for newer versions. While there ware Java 1.0, and 1.1 we used `Java 2` term to describe 1.3 or 1.4. Starting from 1.5 we used name `Java 5` (similarly 1.6 was simply Java 6). So yes, if result of `java -version` was like `9.0.1` it represents Java 9 (which is technically the same as `1.9` but lets stop using that notation already like Java authors did).

Comment: omg, I missed, that they changed versioning schema, my bad...

Answer (score 0):

It compiles for Me You would haven't set up JDK properly as per my mind. This won't be an answer but seems like an environment problem.

It shows output

```
Book 1: New book
Title: Big Java
Author: Horstmann
Year: 2014
Price: 150.0
Type: Paperback

Book 2: Used book
Title: Java
Author: Deitel
Year: 1999
Price: 120.0
Selling Price: 90.0

Book 3: New book
Title: JavaScript
Author: Hoque
Year: 2005
Price: 80.5
Type: Hardcover

Book 4: New book
Title: C++
Author: Smith
Year: 2004
Price: 135.0
Type: Paperback

Book 5: Used book
Title: C
Author: Jones
Year: 2000
Price: 110.0
Selling Price: 66.0

****************************************

******* BOOKS BELOW  $100.0
Book 2:Used Book 
Title: Java
Author: Deitel
Year: 1999
Price: 120.0
Selling Price: 90.0

Book 3:New Book 
Title: JavaScript
Author: Hoque
Year: 2005
Price: 80.5
Type: Hardcover

Book 5:Used Book 
Title: C
Author: Jones
Year: 2000
Price: 110.0
Selling Price: 66.0

********* ALL PAPERBACK BOOKS
Book 1:NewBook
Title: Big Java
Author: Horstmann
Year: 2014
Price: 150.0
Type: Paperback

Book 4:NewBook
Title: C++
Author: Smith
Year: 2004
Price: 135.0
Type: Paperback
```

Comment: You should be more specific. Even if this is correct answer it won't help someone else...

Comment: Previous one is a mistake sorryr

Comment: please add steps to follow, like `java -version` and `javac` with output for OP to verify ;-)

Comment: While "You would haven't set up JDK properly" may be true, it is worth remembering that "works for me" is usually not high quality/acceptable answer here (more info: [Are “works for me” answers valid?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118992),
[Are “Your code works fine for me” answers acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277923)). To improve your answer show steps which let you run OP code without problems.

Comment: @Pshemo On the other hand link you provided it reads: "...the question is lacking in sufficient information..."

Comment: what are your java -version java and javac outputs?

Comment: Yes but later it says "*There are close reasons specifically for questions like this... Posting an answer to say that the question does not contain enough information to be answerable is not an answer to the question*". In short, not every question must be answered here. We want to gather only high quality questions which properly describe faced problem so others with that problem could find it and potential solutions. If question's quality lack feel free to move on to next one.

Comment: Yes But is there any way to say the question is wrong?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. It states that "Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above: 1. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or *error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.". This question doesn't let us reproduce this problem. We can ask OP for more info via comments, but before getting it we don't need to answer it.

Comment: @PrathibhaChiranthana No problem.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Prathibha Chiranthana

```
c:\TMP\Test>c:\java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\java.exe -version
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)

c:\TMP\Test>c:\java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\javac.exe -version
javac 9.0.4

c:\TMP\Test>dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is DA2F-C2CC

 Directory of c:\TMP\Test

2018-02-07  17:11    <DIR>          .
2018-02-07  17:11    <DIR>          ..
2018-02-07  17:07             5,771 Test.java
               1 File(s)          5,771 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  13,145,710,592 bytes free

c:\TMP\Test>c:\java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\javac.exe Test.java

c:\TMP\Test>
```

Did you try different folder, not C:\Users\JohnD\Desktop\ ?